# react-native-git-upgrade not working

Tags: android, react-native

I just tried to run react-native-git-upgrade by following the documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html). After running the upgrade, I then tried to start my project using `react-native run-android` but got the following errors (see below).

I also tried to follow the "Alternative" way of upgrading from that documentation but eventually ended up with the same error shown below.

How should I proceed to get the upgrade working properly?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.0.1.
     Required by:
         OrderEntry:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.43.3
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.0.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/1.0.1/fresco-1.0.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/1.0.1/fresco-1.0.1.pom'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.0.1.
     Required by:
         OrderEntry:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.43.3
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.0.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/imagepipeline-okhttp3/1.0.1/imagepipeline-okhttp3-1.0.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/imagepipeline-okhttp3/1.0.1/imagepipeline-okhttp3-1.0.1.pom'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve this. It turned out to be an issue with gradle not being able to access the google repositories due to proxy issues.  To resolve it, I added a gradle.properties file to my `C:\Users\my_user_id>\.gradle` folder with the following values:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=your_proxy.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80

systemProp.https.proxyHost=your_proxy.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
```

Once I added that file, I actually ran into more problems which you can read about [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9136), but I finally got things running.

I am not sure why the project ran ok on the previous react-native version without needing the gradle.properties file.  Anyway, hope this helps if anyone has the same problem.